# need a div with 2 images floating right and left and text in btwn them which to be placed in the exact center of the div

Tags: html, css, text, centering

```
<div class="wrapper" style="border-bottom: 2px solid black;text-align:center;">
    <div class="left" style="float:left;">
        <img class="styleLogo" src="ss.png">
    </div>
    <div class="right" style="float:right;">
        <a href="home.html">
           <img class="styleHome" src="home.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="center" style="text-align:left; margin:0 auto !important; display:inline-block">
        <h2 class="heading1">ss</h2>
        <h2 class="heading2">yyyy</h2>
        <h5 class="subHeading1">jjjjjj</h5>
        <h5 class="subHeading2">yyyyyy</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code i tried.pls help.i want  to make ss.png float to right and home.png float to left and the headings shouls be in the exact center of div with wrapper class.

Comment: You are on the right track with the `float` method.  Taking care of your floats first then the center.  You might also try [CSS grid-container](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid_container.asp).  I used the float method in the footer socket of [my website](https://golden-painting.com/).  Use the inspector to figure out what I did.

Comment: can you show  me the code.how to apply in this code.

Comment: I put your code in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/gzwo1edj/6/) and it seems to be working how you want.  what is wrong with the behavior?

Comment: If you go with the float method, you will need to [contain the floats](https://pageaffairs.com/notebook/containing-floats/) somehow.  Easiest way might be to add a fourth div that is empty with style `clear: both;` .  Check [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/gzwo1edj/9/)

Comment: Do you mean that each heading should be centered vertically [like this?](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/gzwo1edj/12/)?

Comment: Not sure if you saw my answer to this question. Placing the right image at the bottom of the wrapper is a different question. Do some research on horizontal alignment of elements (divs), try to write the code yourself, then if you still can’t get it then post a new question

Comment: You could always position it absolutely instead of floating it to the right.  Position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;

Answer (score 1):

### Using the "float" method:

If you want the center element to ignore the left and right elements and be centered in the viewport regardless of the sizes of the left and right elements, you will need to position the center absolutely to the wrapper (or use javascript to find the widths of left and right and set margins accordingly).  See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/gzwo1edj/25/)

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.center > h2, .center > h5 {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.clearfloats {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <img class="styleLogo" src="https://dummyimage.com/170x170">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <a href="home.html">
      <img class="styleHome" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x45"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <h2 class="heading1">ss</h2>
    <h2 class="heading2">yyyyyyy</h2>
    <h5 class="subHeading1">jjjjjj</h5>
    <h5 class="subHeading2">yyyyyyyyyyyy</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfloats"></div>
</div>
```

To place the right image at the bottom right of the wrapper you could position it absolutely instead of floating it.  Just change the `.right` class [like this:](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/gzwo1edj/28/)

```
.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

### Using the "CSS Grid" method:

You can eliminate floats and absolute positioning.  There are all kinds of options for positioning within the grid.  See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/gzwo1edj/43/)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  justify-self: start;
}

.center {
  align-self: center;
  }

.right {
  align-self: end;
  justify-self: end;
}

.center > h2,
.center > h5 {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <img class="styleLogo" src="https://dummyimage.com/170x170">
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <h2 class="heading1">ss</h2>
    <h2 class="heading2">yyyyyyy</h2>
    <h5 class="subHeading1">jjjjjj</h5>
    <h5 class="subHeading2">yyyyyyyyyyyy</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <a href="home.html">
      <img class="styleHome" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x45"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've expanded the answer to include a CSS Grid method.  Please help other users of StackOverflow by accepting whichever answer you feel best answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="border-bottom: 2px solid black;text-align:center;">
    <div class="flex" style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;justify-content:center;justify-content:space-between;">
        <img class="styleLogo" src="ss.png">
        
        <h2 class="heading1">ss</h2>
        <h2 class="heading2">yyyy</h2>
        <h5 class="subHeading1">jjjjjj</h5>
        <h5 class="subHeading2">yyyyyy</h5>
        
        <img class="styleLogo" src="ss.png">
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For which div i have to give this.can u show me the code.

Comment: Oh wait... separate the two images but put the text in the same div as the text. Put the second image at the last part of div

Comment: i want first image float to left and 2nd one float to the left of the div.the text should appear to the exact center of the div with class wrapper.pls help.urgent.pls show an example code of my requirement.

Comment: no the two images are of different size and the headings should in seperate lines but at the exact center of the div with class wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this kind of structure simply using CSS flexbox, just make the div element with class `wrapper` flexbox and then use the appropriate rules to align your content in it, for example first place the elements in the order you wish them to appear on webpage

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        <img class="styleLogo" src="https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/fff">
    </div>
    <div class="center">
        <h2 class="heading1">ss</h2>
        <h2 class="heading2">yyyy</h2>
        <h5 class="subHeading1">jjjjjj</h5>
        <h5 class="subHeading2">yyyyyy</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <a href="home.html">
           <img class="styleHome" src="https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/fff"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then use this CSS to adjust the content according to your need

```
.wrapper {
      display:-webkit-box;
      display:-ms-flexbox;
      display:flex;
      -webkit-box-pack:justify;
      -ms-flex-pack:justify;
      justify-content:space-between;
      border:1px solid #000;
      align-items:center;
      text-align:center;
}
.left img, 
.right img {
      width:100%;
}
.center {
      min-width:33.33%;
}
```

You can alter the width of your left, right and center divs according to your wish or accommodate the content, and if you want your content to be centered vertically also then just add one new rule to wrapper div `align-items:center;`

If you are not familiar with the concept of flexbox then you can visit this resource for more information https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Edit: as per your requirement to make the center div to stay at exact center irrespective of the size and placement of the divs on sides you can use `position:absolute;` on center div like below:

```
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  border:1px solid #000;
  align-items:center;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.right{
 margin-top:auto;
}
.right img{
  width:50px;
  height:45px;
  display:block;
}
.left img{
  width:170px;
  height:170px;
  display:block;
}
.center{
  min-width:33.33%;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You can check this fiddle also https://jsfiddle.net/dcejbq3s/

Comment: +1 Good job.  If you don't mind cleaning up your code a bit [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/uyzdgfvr/) and edit your answer.

Comment: @ChrisL Thanks for appreciating my answer, I also have cleaned my code as you suggested, just left the browser vendor prefixes for flexbox css.

Comment: Looks great!  Bonus points to expand your answer and include another example using `grid-container` method.

Comment: i will try and get back to you.

Comment: but two images are of differnet sizes.so the text will not come at the exact center.can you show an example with image having different sizes.the right image is a smaller one

Comment: @jaina Please check the js fiddle again, you can do so by decreasing the width of the right div or in your case when you add the smaller image its width will automatically be decreased.

Comment: @ChrisL will surely do that

Comment: but it is not exactly the center.what to do?

Comment: i have given a image with dimension 170*170 on left and 50*45 on right

Comment: anyone pls help

Comment: So you want the center element to ignore the left and right elements and be perfectly centered in the viewport regardless of the size of the left and right elements.  This will require absolute positioning of the center element.

Comment: As @ChrisL suggested, this can't be achieved without using `position:absolute;` so I have updated the fiddle using `position:absolute;` for center div. But for this you will have to make sure that the content of center div does not increase then height of parent div because then it will overflow the parent div and this is already happening so I have set the overflow for the parent to hidden. Please check fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/a943huyz/

Comment: No worries, +1 for you to sort it first, even I get to learn something from you today, thank you.

Comment: ya it worked .eventhough not exact center.can you help me to place the  right image at the bottom of the wrapper div.at the right bottom

Comment: @chris pls help

Comment: give the div with class `right` `margin-top:auto;` I updated the fiddle you can check https://jsfiddle.net/6nxskcmd/